# Maximum likelihood of normal distribution with mean $0$

Tags: statistics, maximum-likelihood

If

$$f(x;\theta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\theta}}e^{-x^2/(2\theta)},$$

what is the maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta$?

(I answered my own question, since writing all this code made me aware the flaws in my original math. Perhaps some may find a use for it. $\LaTeX$ is too much grind to simply delete it...)

Answer (score 1):

The likelihood function is:

$$L(\theta) = (2\pi\theta)^{-\frac{n}{2}}e^{-\sum{x_i^2}/(2\theta)}$$

and the log-likelihood is:

$$l(\theta) = -\frac{n}{2}\ln{(2\pi)}-\frac{n}{2}\ln{(\theta)}-\frac{\sum{x_i^2}}{2\theta}$$

Differentiating:

$$\frac{d l(\theta)}{d\theta} = -\frac{n}{2\theta}+\frac{\sum{x_i^2}}{2\theta^2}$$

Equating to 0 yields:

$$\hat{\theta} = \frac{\sum{x_i^2}}{n}$$